# Dapper version 1.12.0.0 XML parameter no longer working

Tags: c#, dapper

When passing an xml string through dapper to SQL Server 2008, dapper seems to be creating a parameter for each one of characters in the xml string.

For example, if the string is `<outer></outer>` it appears to be creating a parameter
for each character ( '<', 'o', 'u', 't', etc..)

In old version the code would pass one parameter (namely the xml parameter that was specified) into the stored procedure.

Set up code looks like the following -

```
var xml = @"
<OuterElement>
  <InnerElement>1</InnerElement>
  <InnerElement>2</InnerElement>
  <InnerElement>3</InnerElement>
  <InnerElement>4</InnerElement>
</OuterElement>";

var parameters = new Dapper.DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@XmlParameter", xml, DbType.Xml); 
SqlMapper.Query(
  connection, 
  "dbo.TestXmlInput", 
  parameters, 
  commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
  commandTimeout: 60
);
```

My questions are as follows:
Can anyone else reproduce this?
If so, Was this change intentional or a bug?
Is there a workaround for achieving xml parameter passing?

The generated SQL looks like this:

```
exec dbo.TestXmlInput (@XmlParameter1, @XmlParameter2, @XmlParameter3, ...)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, `DbType.Xml` had been internally hijacked to represent something different. This is being problematic. Basically, when I made parameter expansion (`where Id in @ids`) work in `DynamicParameters`, it broke xml.

I have now created a different way of representing this, and pushed the updated source to google-code and github. If you use the updated code, it should work fine. I haven't deployed NuGet yet - let me know if you need this.

Comment: Have the changes been deployed to nu get yet?

Comment: For future readers, I was able to get the code (in the question) to work...with a DotNetCore project using ".nuget\packages\dapper\1.50.5".  Make sure you pick "CommandType.StoredProcedure" (duh!) This is a good read about how DynamicParameters map to Xml datatype.  : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/889668/SQL-Server-Dapper